# Xubuntu: LibreOffice dispays no menu icons

Tags: xubuntu, icons, libreoffice, menu, gtk3

I face an issue while using LibreOffice on Xubuntu: LO does not display the icons in the menus.
I don't know if the problem is specific to the gtk3 VCL but I don't have the problem with x11 and qt5 VCL (`export SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gen; soffice` or `export SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=qt5; soffice`).

With gtk3 as VCL, in Tools, Options, View, Visibility sub-menu, there is no **Icons in menu** option whereas it is available and effectif with x11 and qt5.

There is a discussion on LO forums: [Cannot enable menu icons in LO 6.4.2](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/234567/cannot-enable-menu-icons-in-lo-642/), but no solution is provided.

It's not an important problem but the menu are less readable and a little bit sad and it looks like a regression from previous versions...
Does anyone has a solution to fix this?

---

Xubuntu 20.0431 (kernel 5.4.0-42-generic)
LibreOffice Version: 6.4.6.2, Build ID: 1:6.4.6~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Answer (score 1):

Thit is a bug. The last time we were able to show icons in menu was in version 6.3.4.x.
The following is a **workaround** for LibreOffice 7.0.3+ launched in a GT3 GUI (for example in Cinnamon, MATE or XFCE).

Step 1: In in LibreOffice menu Tools: Options: Advanced, click "Open Expert Configuration"

Step 2: Search "IconsInMenu". Then, set **ShowIconsInMenues** to **true**, **IsSystemIconsInMenus** to **false**.

Step 3: Restart LibreOffice.